# Resize image in C# with aspect ratio and crop central image so there are no gaps

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to resize user uploaded images to a landscape dimensions e.g. 450w and 250h while maintaining aspect ratio, but to avoid resized images like portrait images having gaps on the side I would like to crop the centre of the image to fill the resized dimensions.

I have found plenty of code to resize images while maintaining aspect ratio but not what I am looking for above, I'm hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should pass needToFill = true:

```
public static System.Drawing.Image FixedSize(Image image, int Width, int Height, bool needToFill)
{
    #region calculations
    int sourceWidth = image.Width;
    int sourceHeight = image.Height;
    int sourceX = 0;
    int sourceY = 0;
    double destX = 0;
    double destY = 0;

    double nScale = 0;
    double nScaleW = 0;
    double nScaleH = 0;

    nScaleW = ((double)Width / (double)sourceWidth);
    nScaleH = ((double)Height / (double)sourceHeight);
    if (!needToFill)
    {
        nScale = Math.Min(nScaleH, nScaleW);
    }
    else
    {
        nScale = Math.Max(nScaleH, nScaleW);
        destY = (Height - sourceHeight * nScale) / 2;
        destX = (Width - sourceWidth * nScale) / 2;
    }

    if (nScale > 1)
        nScale = 1;

    int destWidth = (int)Math.Round(sourceWidth * nScale);
    int destHeight = (int)Math.Round(sourceHeight * nScale);
    #endregion

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmPhoto = null;
    try
    {
        bmPhoto = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(destWidth + (int)Math.Round(2 * destX), destHeight + (int)Math.Round(2 * destY));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("destWidth:{0}, destX:{1}, destHeight:{2}, desxtY:{3}, Width:{4}, Height:{5}",
            destWidth, destX, destHeight, destY, Width, Height), ex);
    }
    using (System.Drawing.Graphics grPhoto = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto))
    {
        grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        grPhoto.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        grPhoto.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        Rectangle to =  new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)Math.Round(destX), (int)Math.Round(destY), destWidth, destHeight);
        Rectangle from = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
        //Console.WriteLine("From: " + from.ToString());
        //Console.WriteLine("To: " + to.ToString());
        grPhoto.DrawImage(image, to, from, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        return bmPhoto;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with image size, cropped image size is about twice as big as original image. Any fix?

Comment: I had the same problem about the filesize of the new cropped image being about the same as the original. Couple of options worked for me: change PixelFormat to a less expensive 32 bits per pixel, set horizontal and vertical resolutions to 72 (if using for web), finally when saving make sure you're specifying an image format just as ImageFormat.jpeg

Comment: Its work for me , but only problem is image gets zooming so it does not display whole image. any suggestion?

Comment: Why do you have `_interpolationMode`, `_compositingQuality`, and `_smoothingMode` defined as private members?

Comment: On another note, when using this example with a 768x576 image and passing in 50x50 for the width and height, the resulting image is 50x49. Not 50x50. Something here isn't right.

Comment: @kehrk please try updated version of answer, it should fix precision issue

Comment: @SergeyOsypchuk Yeah, that did it. I ended up going with that solution as well. Good job.

Comment: it does not work if the size of image either width or height is smaller than the copped needed widh and height. any suggestions?

Comment: i figured it out by commenting out the lines - if (nScale > 1)  nScale = 1;

Comment: how can I execute it from url? like: **thumb.aspx?image=test.jpg&width=100&height=50&needToFill=true**