# Resize and Fit Image in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, image

I have the following:

```
using (bmp == new Bitmap(50, 50)) {
    using (g == Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

The user provides my app an image which my app has to resize and also *fit* the entire image.

The problem with the above code is that it *stretches* the image, not *fit* (as a 4:3 movie fits in a widescreen TV leaving blackbars).

Does anyone have any solution for this? Also, I would prefer not to use GDI.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to crop an image using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10323949/1255010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the size of the input image into account. Here is a code snippet that should get you into the right direction:

```
int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 50, y2 = 50;
if (img. Width <= img.Height) 
{
   // compute x1, y1 to fit img horizontally into bmp
}
else
{
   // compute y1, y2 to fit img vertically into bmp
}

g.DrawImage(img, x1,y1, x2,y2);
```

Also notice that you are asking for resizing an image in WPF but using System.Drawing which uses GDI+ under the hood.